# Only one resolution available at 1024 x 768 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

I run Ubuntu 16.04. I am a new user.

There is only one resolution available at the `Display menu 1024 x 768 (4:3)` and I cannot change it. When I ran `xrandr` this is the output

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
```

default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* `

Result of running `lspci | grep VGA` (for finding the graphics card)

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.  [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]`
```

Is there anything I can do?